# How to specify generic key constraint in function argument

Tags: javascript, typescript

I might be going about this the wrong way, I just wanted to have a little bit of fun in code today. I'm sure a library already does this as well.

I am creating a generic `pushUnique` function that determines if a new object being pushed to an array is unique based on a key, and if so, push it.

So far I have little more than pseudo-code that doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```
  pushUnique<T, U>(arr: T[], obj: T, key: U = null) {
    if (key !== null) {
      const index = arr.findIndex(o => o.key === obj.key);
    }
  }
```

How can I get the object name of the key and specify it for the findIndex function?

---

EDIT:

With help from Titian Cernicova-Dragomir this is my final solution for now that works great for my POC needs!

```
export class Utils {
  pushUnique<T, U>(arr: T[], obj: T, key: (o: T) => U = null, logVerbose: boolean = false): void {
    if (logVerbose === true) {
      console.log('pushUnique called');
    }

    if (typeof obj === 'object' && key === null) {
      console.warn('Object defined in pushUnique is complex, but a key was not specified.');
    } else if (typeof obj !== 'object' && key !== null) {
      console.warn('Object is not complex, but a key was specified');
    }

    const index = key !== null ? arr.findIndex(o => key(o) === key(obj)) : arr.indexOf(obj);
    if (index === -1) {
      arr.push(obj);
    } else {
      if (logVerbose === true) {
        console.log('Duplicate object, not added');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the key typed as `keyof T` meaning it must be a key of whatever `T` is passed in and then you can just use index access to get the value:

```
class Util {
    pushUnique<T>(arr: T[], obj: T, key: keyof T) {
        if (key !== null) {
            const index = arr.findIndex(o => o[key] === obj[key]);
        }
    }
}

new Util().pushUnique([{a: 1}], {a :2 }, "a")
new Util().pushUnique([{a: 1}], {a :2 }, "b") //err
```

You can also use a function instead of `keyof` but this is the JS/TS way of doing things:

```
class Util {
    pushUnique<T, U>(arr: T[], obj: T, key: (o: T) => U) {
        if (key !== null) {
            const index = arr.findIndex(o => key(o) === key(o));
        }
    }
}

new Util().pushUnique([{a: 1}], {a :2 }, o => o.a)
new Util().pushUnique([{a: 1}], {a :2 }, o => o.b) //err
```

Comment: So would I pass that in as a string value then? Like `pushUnique(myArr, newObj, 'Id')` ?

Comment: @Reed added usage example, yes it would be a string but it would also be checked by the compiler

Comment: Awesome that does work! Is there a way I could perhaps pass it in dynamically as a function argument however? Instead of explicitly specifying through string? It would be nice to take advantage of typescripts intellisense.

Comment: @Reed you have intelisense for strings that are `keyof T`  type "|" and at the cursor | you will get intelisense

Comment: @Reed added function version as well

Comment: That's excellent, and exactly what I was looking for! So are we just specifying that we accept in the lambda object of T and we are returning object type U from T? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: @Reed yeah that is the gist of it. `any` would probably work as well since we don't use `U` in any other position. This solution allows you to access nested object so it's not necessary for the result to be a value in the object